# How to open keyboard shortcuts settings window from terminal?

Tags: gnome3

I want to open a window from the first screenshot with a terminal command, but the best I could find is `gnome-control-center keyboard` (that gives me a window from second screenshot)

[image: Keyboard shortcuts settings window]

[image: Keyboard settings window]

Using `man` command, I found this for keyboard panel:

```
You can open this panel on a specific tab by passing typing or shortcuts as extra argument.
```

But when I try `gnome-control-center keyboard shortcuts`, it opens the same window (2nd screenshot)

I using GNOME 3.38.4, on Pop!_OS 21.04